# Sum of INT_MAX and INT_MAX

Tags: c, buffer-overflow, integer-overflow

If I declare two max integers in C:

```
int a = INT_MAX;
int b = INT_MAX;
```

and sum them into the another int:

```
int c = a+b;
```

I know there is a buffer overflow but I am not sure how to handle it.

Comment: You might have to declare a long long int which has a much greater size(8 bytes) than a normal integer (4 bytes)

Comment: What behavior are you hoping for?

Comment: @Mihir That's one of my options but my objection is handling it with ints :)

Comment: @Howlium Integer overflow?

Comment: @Mihir That depends on the implementation; they can be of equal size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This causes undefined behavior since you are using signed integers (which cause undefined behavior if they overflow).

You will need to find a way to avoid the overflow, or if possible, switch to unsigned integers (which use wrapping overflow).

One possible solution is to switch to long integers such that no overflow occurs.
Another possibility is checking for the overflow first:

```c
if( (INT_MAX - a) > b) {
    // Will overflow, do something else
}
```

Note: I'm assume here you don't actually know the exact value of `a` and `b`.

Comment: `if( (INT_MAX - a) > b)`?  And if `a` is negative?  *One possible solution is to switch to long integers*  And if `long` is the same size as `int`?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yes, the example check does not handle negative numbers (since OP talked about buffers I assumed a and b were positive indices or the like.) If `long` is not large enough, a longer long integer must be used.

Answer (score 1):

For the calculation to be meaningful, you would have to use a type large enough to hold the result. Apart from that, overflow is only a problem for signed `int`. If you use unsigned types, then you don't get undefined overflow, but well-defined wrap-around.

In this specific case the solution is trivial:

```
unsigned int c = (unsigned int)a + (unsigned int)b; // 4.29 bil
```

Otherwise, if you truly wish to know the signed equivalent of the raw binary value, you can do:

```
int c = (unsigned int)a + (unsigned int)b;
```

As long as the calculation is carried out on unsigned types there's no danger (and the value will fit in this case - it won't wrap-around). The result of the addition is implicitly converted through assignment to the signed type of the left operand of `=`. This conversion is implementation-defined, as in the result depends on signed format used. On 2's complement mainstream computers you will very likely get the value `-2`.